# Python FPDF output pdf file version upper than 1.3 (Acrobat 4.x)

Tags: python, mime-types, fpdf

I'm creating pdf files using FPDF.
FPDF create file version 1.3 (Acrobat 4.x)

Is there a way to output files in a version upper to 1.3? (like 1.5, or 1.6)

I need it because I'm trying to attach the file to an email using MIMEApplication, but MIME do not works if a try to attach pdf version 1.3

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the source code to version

https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/cb3340806c140b6e63eb4ce9d6230be84fba456e/fpdf/fpdf.py#L146

update:
it doesn't have with PDF version
i added a working example with PDF 1.3

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from os.path import basename

from fpdf import FPDF

# pdf as string
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!')

name = 'hello.pdf'
s = pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')

send_from = '***@gmail.com'
email_list = ['***@gmail.com']
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'test'
msg['From'] = 'SCRIPT NOTIFICATION'
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(email_list)
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)

costext = 'file attached below'
msg.attach(MIMEText(costext))

part = MIMEApplication(
    s,
    Name=basename(name)
)
# After the file is closed
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(name)
msg.attach(part)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
    server.sendmail(send_from, email_list, msg.as_string())

except:
    print("failed to send email")
```

[image]

Comment: after modify the source code as you suggest, MIME still not work... maybe is not a problem of pdf version...

Comment: please submit a sample of your email code in a new question mayabe

Comment: although i answered what you asked, i decided to provide you with a working example, see updated answer